# Queria adicionar mais de uma permissão nas roles do springSecurity

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spring-security

Gostaria de saber qual a forma correta de adicionar mais de uma permissão para mesma pasta no springSecurity pois queria que o admin também tivesse o mesmo acesso do usuário comum porem com uma pagina a mais.

```
 <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="false">

    <intercept-url pattern="/View/UnSecured/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/View/Secured/user/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_COMMON')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/View/Secured/adm/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/img/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/theme/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="Pacotes de Código-fonte/**" access="permitAll"/>

    <!-- Custom login page -->
    <form-login always-use-default-target="true"
                default-target-url="/View/Secured/user/index.jsf"
                authentication-failure-url="/login.xhtml?auth=fail"
                login-page="/login.jsf"/>

    <!-- Custom logout page -->
     <logout logout-success-url="/login.jsf" />
</http>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Gostaria de saber qual a forma correta de adicionar mais de uma
>   permissão para mesma pasta no springSecurity...

Você pode usar a expressão hasAnyRole([role1,role2]),exemplo:

```
 <intercept-url pattern="/View/Secured/user/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_COMMON')" />
```

Você pode ver esta expressão e várias outras na [documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html).

Comment: Isso deu certo muito obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Vc pode fazer organizar as pastas e adicionar o acesso desta forma

```
 <intercept-url pattern="/View/Secured/user/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_COMMON')" />
```

o `access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_COMMON')"` vai fazer o admin ter acesso a todas paginas dentro de **View/Secured/user**. Os **(asteriscos duplos) significa que ele tem acesso ao diretório e seus sub-diretórios, se vc deixar somente com 1, ele só vai acessar a pasta daquele diretório.
Se teu caso não for esse, te aconselho a criar um diretório compartilhado só com as paginas que os 2 roles dividem, como por exemplo, eu uso o diretório de edição de usuário compartilhado, e adicionar esse permissão dupla, porque ambos roles editam as informação de perfil na mesma pagina

Comment: quando adicionei essa parte access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') and hasRole('ROLE_COMMON')" ele simplesmente não deixa mais acesso

Comment: perdão, eu vou editar, cometi um erro ai, a condição AND so permite acesso se ele tiver os dois ROLE, basta trocar para OR

Comment: Tranquilo eu ja tinha aplicado e percebido, muito obrigado.